# Getting multiple lines and then single char from keyboard in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I enter:

- Joe Smith (press enter)
- IT engineer (press enter)
- Y (press enter)

What happens then, is that the loop occurs again but you cant enter `your first and last name` a second time.

`String name = s.nextLine();` Always seems to be an empty line after the loop executes once.

Why is that?

Code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.printl('Enter your first and last name:');
    String name = s.nextLine();

    System.out.printl('Enter your job description:');
    String job = s.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Press Y for loop ..");
    char answer = s.next().charAt(0);
} while(answer == 'Y');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.printl()` should be `System.out.println()`

You should use double quotes for Strings.

```
 System.out.printl('Enter your first and last name:');//<----single quote
```

Variable `answer` is out of scope as In java the scope is restricted to  `{}`. Declare `answer` before the `do-while` loop(at the top).

Instead of using `char answer = s.next().charAt(0);`, use `answer = s.nextLine().charAt(0);`

For more information please check [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Here is your modified code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    char answer; //<----declare the variable here 

do {
    System.out.println("Enter your first and last name:"); //<---use double quotes
    String name = s.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your job description:");//<---use double quotes
    String job = s.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Press Y for loop ..");
    answer = s.nextLine().charAt(0); //<---use nextLine() here 
}while(answer == 'Y');
}
```